# Как установить модуль в Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Нужно использовать компонент Navigation Drawer. Но его нет в Eclipse, скачать его можно [отсюда](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top), но не понятно как его устанавливать. Может, как-нибудь через SDK, но там я ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе не нужно ставить никаких плагинов, а достаточно добавить Support Library в твою SDK[image]

там же в хелпе все написано)

This lesson describes how to implement a navigation drawer using the DrawerLayout APIs available in the Support Library